# How Get parameter that has been posted by HTTP POST

Tags: c#, http-post, mailgun

I am using webhooks inside the mailgun API in my C# web app. http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#webhooks

In webhooks I have to provide a URL in mailgun control panel then mailgun will make an HTTP POST to my URL and send some parameters. I got a temporary URL from this website - http://requestb.in/and set it in mailgun to receive the HTTP post. How I can get the parameters that have been sent via post?

I was thinking using:

string domain = Request.Params["domain"];

but it is empty. I am confused should I have any request to that temp url?

Answer (score 0):

Make a HttpPost method and pass the parameters' names as method parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myMethod(param1, param2,..){}
```

the parameters names should be the same as the passing parameters in the request, or have the same name as the input they are coming from in the form

Comment: I am not doing the POST, they going to post to this URL: http://requestb.in/whx7zwwh and I need to get them. where I have to put this URL?